# graph viewer/drawer for c#?

Tags: c#, drawing, graph

Is there a good C# library for drawing/visualizing graphs? I'm talking about node-path visualization instead of line graphs or the like. (preferably native, not wrappers for pstricks or anything like that)
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some pointers:

- [QuickGraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph/) is an open-source general graphing library, it supports MSAGL and graphviz
- [MSAGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_Layout_Execution_Engine) is Microsoft's graph layout engine
- [Netron Reloaded](http://netron-reloaded.sourceforge.net/) is a .NET graphing library (but it looks like there was no new development on the project in the last 3 years)

Answer (score 1):

Native:

- Graph# (open source) (also based on QuickGraph)
- [Netron](http://www.orbifold.net/default/?p=1936) (abandonware); G2

There are plenty of diagram editing packages but I don't know how good they are at layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a native one, but I was involved in developing a [product](http://www.roomsolutions.net/insurance-software/data-warehouse/acumen-advantage.aspx) where someone built a wrapper around [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) without much trouble.  This worked by using the API to render out to a file and then displaying the file using the image viewer control.

If you can't find what you want in a native .Net library I have definitely seen people get good results by wrapping graphviz in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try [aiSee](http://www.aisee.com/) or have a look at [this list](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Math/Combinatorics/Software/Graph_Drawing/).