# Graph Generator for C#

Tags: graph, c#-2.0

I have recently just took up coding in C#(.NET 2.0) again and I was wondering if there are any tools/library's that I can use to generate graphs/statistics from a database, Like what [jpgraph](http://jpgraph.net/) does for PHP.

I plan on using it to make a simple windows application to generate the uptime/downtime of various websites.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [graph viewer/drawer for c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874639/graph-viewer-drawer-for-c)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Chart Control

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c

[Edit] - Oops, this if for Net 3.5.   But it's a good reason to upgrade!

Comment: ok..but isn't there anything for 2.0?  I would like this to be my last resort.

Comment: I dont think there is very much functionality for 2.0 out there. Is there a reason that you don't want to use 3.5?

Comment: Because I only have vs2005 to work with. But between upgrading to vs2008 to going web I think I would most likely go the web route due to company policy

Answer (score 0):

Check out the silverlight graphing libraries. You might need to upgrade from .NET 2.0 though.

Also if you plan to use the web, you can always resort to javascript and jquery libraries out there with graphing abilities.

Comment: If I'm gonna go the web route I would have just used PHP and be done with it, no offense to the .NET crowd but I'm just more comfortable with PHP for the web.